# If LRAS shifts right, won't PPC also shift outward?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth

[image]

Hi, I was solving this question. Here are the answers:

[image]

I am really confused about part (c) & part (d).

My understanding is that when LRAS shifts right, the PPC will shift outwards, to show economic growth, so a right (left) shift in LRAS means outward (inward) shift in PPC, and vice-versa. Can a country have a shift in LRAS without any shift in PPC and vice-versa?

However, the answers say otherwise. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If LRAS shifts right, won't PPC also shift outward?

Yes, that is correct if LRAS shifts right PPC must also shift outwards.

> However, the answers say otherwise. Can anyone please explain this to me?

The answers do not say otherwise. None of the answers states that shift in LRAS wont expand PPF. Next time period PPF will be larger than the present time period PPF showed in the answers.

Comment: I am talking about the point Z. Shouldn't point Z be on a newer curve outward?

Comment: @MangoPizza nope of course not. The z point is on the old PPF, once that saving gets invested it will expand PPF but that happens in second time period.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.